# Generate insert script to restore table from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to delete some orphan records from the prod table. The records I need to delete is returned by below query. However, before doing that I would like to generate a rollback plan where I can reinsert the records back quickly. Therefore, I need to create insert script from the select statement below. I have been struggling with this for a while and now at the point of giving up. I would appreciate if someone can guide me to the right direction:

```
Select *
from ALogs al
where al.ActEnId is not null
and not exists (select * from ActEn ae where ae.Id = al.ActEnId)
```

Comment: Why not simply either put the delete inside a transaction that you can rollback or insert the data into a temp table before you delete it.

Comment: A Transaction seems like the right thing to use here.

Comment: I assume OP is not planning on leaving his transaction open for some extended period so that he can validate the data. I'm guessing a transaction is not the right thing to use here. Maybe OP can clarify the purpose? Because that would change my approach, for sure.

Comment: You can INSERT INTO a table from that SELECT statement to store copies of those rows in a new table, so that if you need to bring them back you can. That seems a better option than trying to create INSERT statements (although that's totally possible to do too).

Comment: A dba should know that the very FIRST step is to make a backup before performing any destructive action on a production database. Next, you need to identify a method to determine if your query correctly affects the database. A table named Alogs doesn't sound that important but you are the only one that knows. You can count the rows before and after your script as a very basic test. Perhaps re-run the select statement afterwards and verify that orphans no longer exist. Given the column name involved - ActEnId - is there (or should there be) a foreign key between these tables?

Answer (score 1):

This is an option:

```
Select *
into test
from ALogs al
where al.ActEnId is not null
and not exists (select * from ActEn ae where ae.Id = al.ActEnId)
```

Simple [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8b70df7e456eb36a3a7f727197f8973)

You can do the same with any number of columns: 
[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f4f0891588804009a26ac8c7c8bf0a45)